# Merge in R only shows Header

Tags: r

I have 3 large excel databases converted to csv. I wish to combine these into one by using R.

I have tagged the 3 files as `dat1`,`dat2`,`dat3` respectively. I tried to merge `dat1` and `dat2` with the name `myfulldata`, and then merge `myfulldata` with `dat3`, saved as `myfulldata2`.

When I did this though only the headers remained in the combination, essentially none of the contents of the databases were now visible. Screenshot linked below. The numbers of "obvs" in the myfulldata's are noted at 0 despite the respective ovs for each individual component being very large. Can anyone advise how to resolve?

Code:

```
dat1 <- read.csv("PS 2014.csv", header=T) 
dat2 <- read.csv("PS 2015.csv", header=T) 
dat3 <- read.csv("PS 2016.csv", header=T)
myfulldata = merge(dat1, dat2)
myfulldata2 = merge(myfulldata, dat3)
save(myfulldata2, file = "Palisis.RData")
```

[image]

Comment: I assume the 3 dataframes have the same column names.
Check ?merga and also try myfulldata = merge(dat1, dat2, all=T).

Comment: Take a closer look at `?merge`.

Comment: The 3 dataframes have identical headers yes. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `merge` in r is analogous to doing a join between two tables in a database.  I suspect what you want to do is to aggregate your three CSV files row-wise (i.e. union them).  In this case, you can try using `rbind` instead:

```
myfulldata <- rbind(dat1, dat2)
myfulldata <- rbind(myfulldata, dat3)
save(myfulldata, file = "Palisis.RData")
```

Note that this assumes that the number and ideally types of the columns in each data frame from CSV is the same (q.v. doing a `UNION` in SQL).

Comment: Tim, thanks very much for this, exactly the solution to the problem.